# Selenium code is not working for locating an element in Safari, working in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

Can someone help who has worked on Selenium WebDriver?

I have been trying to automate a test scenario using Selenium WebDriver on a Mac machine. When I define Safari as my browser, I am getting and error `"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters"`, even though that elements exists on the page in java code Issues/Bug.

**Note:** the same element can be located when we choose Firefox and Chrome as browser. There  are some similar answers, but none of them is talking about Safari browser and Mac machine.

Comment: Hey shawn! As it stands, your question is pretty hard to debug unless you also add some code to it (post your code snippet!). Please click **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45479254/edit)** 
your question and make sure you have a valid **[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**, 
else, most answers will pretty much be shots-in-the-dark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put some wait. Use fluent wait as below :-

```
WebElement waitsss(WebDriver driver, By elementIdentifier){
     Wait<WebDriver> wait =
                new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                                 .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                                 .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    return wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>()
            {
                public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                       return driver.findElement(elementIdentifier);
                }
                });
}
```

The wait should work for you. If still the problem exists then use `JavascriptExecutor` . It will operate directly through JS. It should work. I am giving an example to click any element using `JavascriptExecutor`

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfd"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I am very new to stackoverflow :) When I tried to vote, I got the message: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes case by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded,but do not change the publicity displayed post score!" – Hereby, I would be pleased to share with me any recommendation. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, you need 15 repo for votes .. just ask 2 more good questions or give good answer on question and get at least one vote up.. once anyone votes up your 2 questions or 1 answer, you will get 10 points which is enough for you to cast vote further on :)